# Creating a function in PySpark to return column

Tags: python, regex, function, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a function to which I need to provide a dataframe and a column. It extracts a string using regex pattern and return is a new dataframe.

However, I want the return to be just the result of regex, just the column.

```py
def extract_strings(dataframe_selected, column_selected):
    dataframe2 = dataframe_selected.withColumn("strings", F.regexp_extract(dataframe_selected[f"{column_selected}"], r"([a-zA-Z]+)", 0))
    return dataframe2
```

I would like to create a function which I could use like

```py
df['new_column'] = extract_strings(df, 'text')
```

Comment: I don't understand the question. You answered your own question by creating the required function. The only correction you need is `df = extract_strings(df,'text')`. The regex extracted data is available in column `strings`.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a function which takes a column and returns a column. But you will need to have a dataframe to put that column in, as columns don't "live" on their own, they need a dataframe to contain them.

Function:

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

def extract_strings(column_selected):
    return F.regexp_extract(column_selected, r"([a-zA-Z]+)", 0)
```

Test:

```py
df = spark.createDataFrame([("abc1",)], ["col_name"])

df.withColumn("new_column", extract_strings("col_name")).show()
# +--------+----------+
# |col_name|new_column|
# +--------+----------+
# |    abc1|       abc|
# +--------+----------+
```